# How do I parse a text file in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone

I need to parse a text file, one line at a time. Also, is there EOF in Objective-C?

Comment: See ParseKit [http://parsekit.com/](http://parsekit.com/)

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044334/objective-c-reading-a-file-line-by-line

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this might work for you:

```
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"myfile.txt"];
NSArray *lines = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

This will give you an array where each element is a line of the string.

Comment: And now something like: NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"myFile.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C is a proper extension of C.  Any C program is a valid Objective-C program.  Among other things, this means that EOF defined in the standard C header "stdio.h" is an EOF marker in Objective-C as well.

Answer (score 2):

**stringWithContentsOfFile** is deprecated.

Here is an updated answer:

```
NSError* error;
NSString *fileContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:txtFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
NSArray *lines = [fileContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```