# read single line from text file in objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, readfile

i'm new to iPhone programming and coding in XCode SDK.I want to access and read the configuration file which i have placed in Resource folder in XCode,my configuration file looks like this

```
@key=value$
@vinu=flower$
@cathy=fruit$
```

I want to compare the key and access the value from configuration file.
Since i'm working with iPhone OS, i cant use NSWorkspace.Hence i'm using NSFileHandle.
This is how my code looks like,

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"configuration" ofType:@"txt"];
NSFileHandle *readHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];

NSString *txtString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: 
                                  [readHandle readDataToEndOfFile] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

please let me know is the procedure correct, and how to proceed. ??

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Do yourself a favor and save it as a plist, and not a straight text file.

However, if you need to read it in like that, the simplest way is to read it into a string and then go from there, ie:

```
NSString * fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

If the file is super large and the only reasonable way to read it is line-by-line, then you can quickly see that this is something that [has come up before](http://www.google.com/search?q=c+read+file+line+by+line+site%3Astackoverflow.com) (Particularly: [Objective-C: Reading a file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044334)).

Comment: My configuration file is not a large file..It just holds 3 to 4 lines of key value pair.I need to match key and acces the corresponding value for it...