# read single line from text file in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, filehandle

I want to read a text file in Objective-C till a specified delimiter 
For eg:if this is my .txt input file ,

```
@abc = name1$ 
@xyz = name2$
```

i want to read abc and assign it in the string variable key,and read name1 till $ and assign it to variable value

for eg:expected output

```
key = abc
value= name1
key = xyz
value= name2
```

Kindly suggest me some solution, which functions are available in objective-C, what is its syntax.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044334/) should help. P.S. Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878815/read-single-line-from-text-file-in-objective-c)?

Answer (score 0):

Get the `-filedescriptor` from the `NSFileHandle`, then use `fdopen` to retrieve a `FILE *`, finally use `fscanf` to read formatted input.

Or, read the whole file into an `NSString` and `-enumerateLinesUsingBlock:` to act on each line individually.