# Split large txt file into more txtfiles

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file, split

I'm having an txt file approximately 1000kb big. Now I want to use objective-c split it into 10 txt files of 100kb.

I haven't really worked with NSRange. Well I know how it works, but then to read from a given location with the length: 'to end of file'... I've no idea how to do that.

Some code on how to split this into multiple 100kb txt file would really help me out here.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

HW:

In that you tagged this question with "iphone" I would suggest that your best approach is to NOT read in the big file first and then go about segmenting it. You don't want to be a memory bully .

Other than that, this question has already been asked and answered in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044334/objective-c-reading-a-file-line-by-line)