# how to store the value of first line of text file through code for iphone

Tags: iphone

how to store the value of first line of text file through code for iphone

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"myfile.txt"];
NSArray *lines = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

Comment: sorry this one is not valid for me i want to store the first line of text value in nsstring and want to print that in lable.text

Comment: In that case you can retrieve the string with : NSString *text = [lines objectAtIndex:0];

Answer (score 0):

*Adam Rosenfield* answered your question here:
[Reading a file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044334/objective-c-reading-a-file-line-by-line/1045440#1045440)