# How do I change C file operation to Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

char buf[32];

FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");

fscanf(fp, "%s", buf);

fclose(fp);

I want to change above C file operations to Objective-C.

How do I change?

Is not there fscanf kind of thing in Objective-C?

Comment: For what it's worth, you can keep this code if you want to. Objective-C is a superset of C, and all the POSIX file stuff is available. See @Micah's answer for the equivalent, though.

Comment: I know Objective-C is a superset of C. But I have to change buf to NSString to do something. Do I have to use [NSString stringWithCString...] after each fscanf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. You can't scan from `FILE *` directly into an `NSString`. However, once you've read into the buffer, you can create an `NSString` from it:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCString: buf encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]; // or whatever
```

***NOTE***, however, that using `fscanf` as you have here will cause a buffer overflow. You must specify the size of the buffer, minus one for the trailing null character:

```
fscanf(fp, "%31s", buf);
```

Comment: Isn't there something like fscanf in Objective C?

Comment: Do I have to use [NSString stringWithCString...] after each fscanf? Actually there are many fscanfs between fopen and fclose.

Comment: `NSScanner` lets you scan from a string into another string; `NSInputStream` lets you read a file. But there's no exact equivalent to `fscanf()` that operates on the Objective-C level, no.

Comment: To convert from a C string to an `NSString`, yes, you must call the factory method for each string you're converting.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use NSData to read in your file, and then create a string from that.

```
NSData *dataContents = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: @"test.txt"];
NSString *stringContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: dataContents 
                                       encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Assuming your file is UTF8.

No sense messing around with buffers.  Let the framework do the dirty work.

EDIT: Responding to your comment, if you really, truly *need* to read it line by line, check out [Objective-C: Reading a file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044334/objective-c-reading-a-file-line-by-line)

Comment: I want to do something while I read file line by line. I don't want do that after I read to the end of file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You just want to read a text file into a string?

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"test.txt" withEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if(!fileContents) {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't read file because of error: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
}
```

This assumes UTF8 encoding, of course.

Comment: I simplified my code too much. There are a lot of stuffs between fopen and fclose. I have to change buf to NSString right after I read line. I don't want to do that after I read whole file.