# Reading text file from app bundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file, sqlite

I am about to read a text file from the app bundle and I have read some of the posts about reading text files such as this: [Objective-C: Reading a file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044334/objective-c-reading-a-file-line-by-line)

I am going to read about 2000 lines of sql queries when the application launch if there is a new data migration. This will probably one happen once each 2nd month or so. Could I use this selector and just split the lines, put them in an array and loop through each index to execute the sqlite3 function, or would this take to much time?

```
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path 
      encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc 
      error:(NSError **)error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, I would batch the operation into a transaction to potentially alleviate overhead with running multiple queries, maybe getting some rollback ability in the case of failure.  I *believe* that sqlite has transaction capability.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try it out?

Seriously though, that is probably fine.  2000 lines of text is what, 200k of data?  That isn't all that much.