# iPhone Objective-C what are the benefits of functions vs instance methods?

Tags: objective-c, function, methods

I found this article on how to read a file line by line, and it **uses a function** to read each line: [Objective-C: Reading a file line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044334/objective-c-reading-a-file-line-by-line)

I'd like to increase my code reuse and put more code into smaller reusable pieces. Should I use Objective-C methods or functions? I'm talking about code that would be executed hundreds of times a minute.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use classes and methods. Code reuse is one of the main goals of [object oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). Code reuse is also one of the main reasons for which [Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) was invented, to add classes and methods to C, which only supported functions and thus no OOP.

Comment: And how exactly does converting a function to an instance method improve code reuse? In particular, what code reuse improvement would there be in the OP scenario?

Comment: @Bavarious, from what I understand, the OP wants to "increase his code reuse and put more code into smaller reusable pieces", in general, not in a particular case. But please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: True; reading it again gives that impression as well. Now I’m not really sure what the question is. :)

Answer (score 3):

Choosing between methods and functions is never a matter of reusability, and quite rarely a matter of speed (anyway, hundreds of times per minute means several times a second, which is almost nothing).

The main points to consider are

1. Will you prefer to **think** in *functions* doing something *to objects* or in *objects* doing something at your command?
2. Are you going to *inherit* from the object and override its behaviour?

In case of reading file line by line I would suggest a simpler approach—unless of course you're doing an OOP assignment or doing OOP just for practice. It's not that as if there were anything wrong with OOP—it's a great technique, by all means use it when you need to model complex behaviour. It's just that for a simple script it's almost always an overkill.

Comment: Lets say I have a loop that needs to iterate over 3 differently named variables. When I was working in java, I would simply define a method method(variableA,VariableB,VariableC) with a certain return type and call that. This produced a very clean code, and allowed me to manage complexity. Somehow this got lost when I switched to objective C, because I'm not a C programmer and did not know when it was proper to use functions and not. I do not intend to override or reuse those functions in other classes, they are just for my own sanity!

Comment: I use a simple technique based on [GRASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_\(object-oriented_design\)) patterns — if I can assign responsibility to an object using any of the approaches listed, I write a method. If I cannot, a function is the way to go.