# Copying text files to NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to get text from text files and put it in a non-editable NSTextView. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: please check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044334/objective-c-reading-a-file-line-by-line

Comment: @lailo: There's no reason to load the text file line by line as the SO question you linked details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Load the file into an [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).
2. Set the NSTextView's string to the loaded string (hint: NSTextView is a subclass of [NSText](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).
3. Ship BetterTextEditor.app and profit.

Prerequisite: Look up the needed methods in the two API reference documents I linked in the steps above.