# Reading file line by line in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

I have a texfile as follows:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
 ....
```

I want to read from file into two arrays of string so that `line1, line3, line 5,...` go into `array1` and `line 2, line 4, line 6,...` go into `array2`. 
Each element of arrays stores one line.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044334/objective-c-reading-a-file-line-by-line check out that link because it has a lot of useful information for what you're doing.

Comment: You can't, fundamentally, read a variable-length record file by individual record.  You've got to read character-by-character, or read blocks and then "deblock" them.  I'd suggest the latter -- read the entire file and do "componentsSeparatedBy..." to get your individual lines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C: Reading a file line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044334/objective-c-reading-a-file-line-by-line)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1) Read file (`[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:]` )

Step 2) Split string (`[NSString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]]` )

Step 3) Iterate over array and insert into your 2 arrays

Comment: @silvansky Sure, but I don't think that is a typical case.  You'd have to have a metric buttload of text before it started to cause problems.