# why does Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "txt") always return nil?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I want to read a text file line by line and display it on an iOS screen using the [example shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31779035/2348597).

Making `textView.text` optional was the only way I could get `readDataFromFile` to run. When I click `load` the function runs but always returns `nil`. I assume this means the file is not found.

For testing purposes I created the text file in Xcode. I also tried saving it on the desktop as well as in the project folder. Either way it was readable from the project navigator. I also tried creating the file using TextEdit because the app ultimately needs to read text files created outside Xcode.

I’d be grateful if someone can explain why the text file is never found, whether there is something else I need to do in order for the project to find it or if the read function returns `nil` for some other reason due to the way I have implemented it. Thanks.

**EDIT** (2)

Thanks for the feedback. In response, I’ve made four minor code changes that allow the text file contents to be written to textView. Changes include: removing the file extension from the filename, adding an array of file names, returning `String` instead of `String?` from `readDataFromFile` and rewriting `UITextView` in code. This has solved problems I am aware of.

Here's the revised code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var textView = UITextView()
var arrayOfStrings: [String]?
var fileNameWithExtension               = "textFile.txt"
let arrayOfFileNames                    = ["textFile1.txt", "textFile2.txt", "textFile3.txt", "textFile4.txt", "textFile5.txt"]

var fileName                            = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //    remove comment in the next statement to test files named in ArrayOfFileNames    
    //    fileNameWithExtension               = arrayOfFileNames[4]

    fileName = fileNameWithExtension.replacingOccurrences(of: ".txt", with: "")

    createTextView()
    createButton()
}

func readDataFromFile(fileName: String) -> String {

   if let path                          = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: nil) {

        print(fileName)

        do {
            let data                    = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            arrayOfStrings              = data.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
            textView.text               = arrayOfStrings?.joined(separator: "\n")

        } catch {
            textView.text               = "file contents could not be loaded"
        }

    } else {
        print(Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "txt") as Any)
        textView.text                   = "\(fileName) could not be found"
    }
    return textView.text
}

func createButton () {
    let button = UIButton();
    button.setTitle(String("Load"), for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 10, width: 200, height: 100)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}

func buttonAction(myButton: UIButton) {
    textView.text = readDataFromFile(fileName: fileName)
    print(textView.text as Any)
}

func createTextView () {
    textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 75.0, width: 340.0, height: 400.0))
    textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.left
    textView.textColor = UIColor.blue
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.view.addSubview(textView)
    }
}
```

**EDIT** (1)

The file is visible in the project navigator. I will assume that means it is in the bundle.

Here is my original code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView?

var arrayOfStrings: [String]?
var fileName                            = "textFile.txt"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createButton()
}

func readDataFromFile(fileName: String) -> String? {

    if let path                         = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "txt") {
        print(fileName)

        do {
            let data                    = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            arrayOfStrings              = data.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
            print(arrayOfStrings as Any)

            textView?.text              = arrayOfStrings?.joined(separator: "/n")
            return textView?.text

        } catch {
            textView?.text              = "file contents could not be loaded"
            return textView?.text
        }

    } else {
        print(Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "txt") as Any)
        textView?.text                  = "\(fileName) could not be found"
        return nil
    }
}

func createButton () {
    let button = UIButton();
    button.setTitle(String("Load"), for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 15, width: 200, height: 100)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}


func buttonAction(myButton: UIButton) {
    print("works")
    textView?.text                      = readDataFromFile(fileName: fileName)
    print(textView?.text as Any)
}
```

**textFile.txt**

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

Comment: `fileName` is supposed to be `textFile` (without extension)

Comment: ... or  call `Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: nil)` if `fileName` already includes the extension ".txt"

Comment: ...or use the URL related API `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "textFile", withExtension:"txt")` which is more descriptive.

Comment: @Martin R, @vadian, when I tried these the function still returned `nil`. I prefer `(forResource: fileName, ofType: nil)` as there are several text files. Last suggestion creates a new path problem in `let data = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8).` Greatly appreciated. Still looking.

Comment: @vadian is that always everywhere paths, are only based on filenames in which filenames never include file types?!

Comment: Did you verify that the file is actually in the bundle?

Comment: @MirekE, I believe it is there. See my edit

Comment: It is there in Xcode, but make sure it gets copied to the package that you run on simulator or your device. Also - your file does not have extension - I believe your code is looking for file with extension txt: `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "textFile", withExtension:nil)`

Comment: @MirekE, yes, but when I tried `url` instead of `path,` I hit a problem with `let data = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8).` I'm looking there again.

Comment: Use path if you like, but remove the txt from the name. I think you have it either in the file name or the `ofType` parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) You have mistake in this line:

```
var fileName = "textFile.txt"
```

should be:

```
var fileName = "textFile"
```

2) Check is your file connected to target:

[image]

Comment: makes no difference

Comment: check, did you set correct target for "textFile.txt"

Comment: I believe you mean: is "textFile.txt" in the bundle. See my edit

Comment: The file also needs to be added to the target. Select the file in the navigator and check its target membership in the utility pane. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147640/what-is-my-target-and-how-do-i-add-a-file-to-it-for-unit-testing

Comment: @Rolleric, I never knew about target membership until now. Thanks. I now understand what Igor was saying. Several changes have now been made and these may have solved the problem. See my latest edit. When I checked the target membership check box on each file it was ticked. That must happen automatically for text files edited in Xcode.

Answer (score 4):

You should consider adding class bundle owner like this:

```
Bundle(for: ViewController.self).path(forResource: "fileName", ofType: "txt")
```

This was implemented from swift 2.0 if I was right.

Comment: you deserve a medal for this! I have a setup with multiple xcode projects. In my `MainApp.xcodeproj` I refer to `MyModule.xcodeproj`, inside `MyModule` I referred to an asset, video file (mp4) that was also part of the `MyModule`s target. But using the code `Bundle.main` inside a file in `MyModule` did not refer to `MyModule` but rather `MainApp`. So using your solution with  `Bundle(for: FileInsideMyModulesTarget.self).path` solved my problem! :D

Comment: This worked for me while using multiple projects with submodules.