# Split up a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How could I make it so that I can split up a string read from a file into separate strings  or make it only read certain line like if i wanted it to only read the first line one the text file and store it into a string. Here is the code i use to read a text file.

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pday11 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"day11.txt"];
    NSString *stringFromFileday11 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pday11 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
//If i used this to read the file how could i split up the "stringFromFileday11" into different strings where every line is a string from the file
```

Comment: Why are you so determined to have these be separate strings? The easiest solution is to combine them into one. Why is that not suitable? Are you actually wanting to append to the file over a long period of time?

Comment: I solved the first part of the question.

Comment: I need to split up the string because the parts of it are used in a if statment

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C: Reading a file line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044334/objective-c-reading-a-file-line-by-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read to a string and split it up

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:<YOUR FILEPATH> encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *array = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

(e.g. Read a first line.)

```
NSString *firstline = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: How could i then split the array up into separate strings

Comment: You can use a for loop, also a while loop.

Comment: Edit: add an example. I hope this helps.

Comment: @user2259486: Are your strings actually separated by newlines?

Comment: Sorry noob mistake i thought that the componentsseparatedbystring was splitting them on new lines thank you so much it fixed so many problems!