# How to read a .txt file line-by-line in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, load

I have a huge .txt file (like 100mb) and I don't want to load all the content into a NSString. So how can I read line by line this file?

I would like something like:

```
while ( endOfFile is not reached )
   line = readline();
```

Comment: Alternative answers here: [Objective-C: Reading a file line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044334/objective-c-reading-a-file-line-by-line).

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible using C code (because ObjectiveC is a superset of C); there's the `fgets` function that reads exactly one line.

```
FILE *file = fopen([filename UTF8String], "r");
char buffer[256];
while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(char)*256, file) != NULL){
    NSString* line = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:buffer];
    NSLog(@"%@",line);
}
```

The only tricky part is the `256` you see in the code. You need to make sure that this number is greater than the number of characters in the longest line of your text file.

Comment: Actually that is one of the answers to the question that I linked to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20257340/1187415 .

Comment: @MartinR I copied it from one of my projects, but it's possible that I copied the snipped form another source (your link maybe) a while ago.