# convert hex to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

i converted to hex by:

```
NSString * hexStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                                  [NSData dataWithBytes:[string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] 
                                                 length:strlen([string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding])]];
```

i converted from foreign language so each character is now 4 bytes in hex.
i have tried to convert it back to nsstring but i didnt get the original string (by [How to convert HEX to NSString in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421282/how-to-convert-hex-to-nsstring-in-objective-c)).

help :)

Comment: What `foreign` language is it?

Comment: Try to see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002652/nsstream-utf8string-nsstring-messy-conversion

Answer (score 3):

A couple of observations:

1. Your technique for converting the string to a `NSData` by getting `cStringUsingEncoding` and then using that to `dataWithBytes` is a little indirect. It's much easier to do:

   ```
   NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   ```
2. If you want to convert a `NSData` back to a `NSString`, you can do:

   ```
   NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   ```
3. You're successfully using `stringWithFormat` to create a hex string representation of your `NSData`. Now the question is how to convert that hex string representation back to a `NSData`. Lots of techniques, but here's one routine that does that:

   ```
   - (NSData *)dataFromHexString:(NSString *)originalHexString
   {
       NSString *hexString = [originalHexString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[ <>]" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [originalHexString length])]; // strip out spaces (between every four bytes), "<" (at the start) and ">" (at the end)
       NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:[hexString length] / 2];
       for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [hexString length]; i += 2)
       {
           NSString *hexChar = [hexString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(i, 2)];
           int value;
           sscanf([hexChar cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], "%x", &value);
           uint8_t byte = value;
           [data appendBytes:&byte length:1];
       }

       return data;
   }
   ```

So, putting this all together, to

```
NSString *string          = @"こんにちは、世界。";
NSData   *data            = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *hexString       = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", data];
NSData   *resultingData   = [self dataFromHexString:hexString];
NSString *resultingString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resultingData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

Each char is 4 bytes in hex? That means it is actually four nibbles, so it is not UTF 8 but UTF 16.

Comment: Not necessarily. A UTF8 character can require anything between one and six bytes (or whose hex string representation of that is between two and twelve bytes). For example, many European characters outside the 7-bit ASCII character set take 16-bits each in UTF8. So do many Arabic characters. Etc. You cannot infer the string encoding solely from the number of bytes per character. In this case, OP is using `NSUTF8StringEncoding`, so we know it's UTF8 and the number of bytes per character is perfectly consistent with that.